# Struggling with a UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: node.js, mongodb, es6-promise

I'm struggling to see where the promise rejection is emerging in the following:

```
MongoClient.connect(mongourl)
    .then(db => {
        console.log("making promises:", typeof lib.getAllData)
        // let promises = packages.map(repo => lib.getAllData(db, repo));
        let promises = [];
        console.log("making promises2")
        // return getAllData(db, packages[0])
        return Promise.all(promises)
            .then(results => {
                console.log("RAW RES", results);
                let missing = results.filter(r => r.error).map(r => r.error)
                return (db, missing);
            })
            // Should never fail as getAllData always resolves
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("err1", err);
                return Promise.reject({db, err})
            });
    }).then(({db, results}) => {
        console.log("RES: ", results);
        db.close();
    }).catch(({db, err}) => {
        console.log("Final Err:", err);
        db.close();
    });
```

What I see in the console is

```
making promises: function
making promises2
RAW RES []
RES:  undefined
Final Err: undefined
(node:7026) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
(node:7026) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I have two questions:

- why is RES `undefined` - I would expect it to be `[]`
- why am I ending up at "Final Err" as there should be no rejections occuring in this script

Comment: You sure your deconstructing the object you get as a callback correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't go through the entire code but from a glance I think you got your [deconstructing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) broken:

```
const test = () => {
    return ('one','two');
}

console.log( test() )
```

Will return `two`, not `{'one', 'two'}` as you suggest here.

So change your code like this:

```
MongoClient.connect(mongourl)
    .then(db => {
        console.log("making promises:", typeof lib.getAllData)
        // let promises = packages.map(repo => lib.getAllData(db, repo));
        let promises = [];
        console.log("making promises2")
        // return getAllData(db, packages[0])
        return Promise.all(promises)
            .then(results => {
                console.log("RAW RES", results);
                let missing = results.filter(r => r.error).map(r => r.error)


                return {db, missing};
                //      ^------- THE CHANGE


            })
            // Should never fail as getAllData always resolves
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("err1", err);
                return Promise.reject({db, err})
            });
    }).then(({db, results}) => {
        console.log("RES: ", results);
        db.close();
    }).catch(({db, err}) => {
        console.log("Final Err:", err);
        db.close();
    });
```

I also suggest to abstract these functions so that you get to a nice promise chain.

## Your questions

> why is RES undefined - I would expect it to be []

Well you return a single variable rather than an object so `db` and `results` is both `undefined`

> why am I ending up at "Final Err" as there should be no rejections occuring in this script

Famous last words ;)
Always assume things will break.

Comment: The other things that looks odd is your `Promise.all` thing... You're returning two things in the first `then` function... I assume this is a copy-past making-things-simpler issue?

Comment: That has helped a little. I no longer pass to the catch, but RES is is still `undefined`. The errors come back when I use the promises currently commented out, but Ill have to work that out in a separate question or by myself

Comment: Feel free to tick this as the answer then and link your new question her as well.

Comment: I will do unless some else can answer why RES is `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

So the error was that I was returning - as Dominik stated:

```
return (db, missing);
```

That should have been

```
return {db, missing};
```

But in my `.then` I was pattern matching for

```
{db, results}
```

and results could not be found as I was returning a field called `missing`